# How to fix a problem with turning my google sheet into JSON?

Tags: json, google-sheets

When I got my google sheet published online,
the link
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/MY_KEY/public/basic?alt=json
gives me

Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.
Please check the address and try again.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crleH.png)

What could be a problem?

I tried to sign out of my second account, but it didn't help.

Comment: This might because of the way you are accessing it or you have publish it.
Check if you have given all the permission to view the file without login.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It has been published. The external link works. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRXQwTn6pMb3oOUIqg7oaaXqiN1NmA7wgpr31D9OXL49LMBOLH0E9bBRaz1c3sZSe8L_pFNHYprC6PO/pubhtml

Comment: But this one doesn't work...   https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/11LuZcNM1NaHIFnF5BS6Wc-aD6hpKQdrnDDO-IUCpM-Q/public/basic?alt=json